# Why do I get "Permission Denied" Firebug console errors while testing jQueryUI sortable?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, firebug, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm getting errors on the Firebug Console while trying to test "connected" Sortable functionality using jQueryUI.  Here's the type of error I receive as soon as I drag a table row:

```
Error: Permission denied to access property 'sortableItem'
  target[ name ] = copy;
```

If I turn Firebug off, the Sortable functionality seems to work just fine.

Here's the code I'm testing:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>ja test</title>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$( ".connected" ).sortable({
        items: 'tbody > tr',
        connectWith: ".connected",

        update: function(e, ui){
              // AJAX code will go here
              alert("hello"); // testing only
                }

        });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>      

<table border="0" width="50%" class="connected" id="unranked">
    <thead>
          <tr class="body-bold">
            <td>id</td>
            <td>Start Date </td>
            <td>End Date </td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody id="sortableUnranked">
        <tr id="contentid-9896">
            <td>A9896</td>
            <td>2013-02-21</td>
            <td>2013-03-31</td>                 
            <td><input class="edit-button" type="button" name="edit" value="Edit"></td>         
        </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be a less than current version of the Firebug add-on FireQuery.  I had version 1.2 installed (and Firefox reported that all my add-ons were current).  When I visited the FireQuery test page (to test FireQuery's functioning):  http://firequery.binaryage.com/test/, I discovered that it also was showing Firebug errors, and the release notes for the most current version, 1.3, said the changes were to fix issues related to the Firefox security model.  When I installed FireQuery 1.3, the FireQuery test page worked without error, and so did my script.